# Apache2 000-Default VHost won't be choosen by a Request

Tags: linux, debian, apache2, apache2.4, debian-stretch

I have a Linux server with Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch) and Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) installed. I wanna host multiple websites on my server. For example one main wesbites and 2-3 smaller websites for friends. I also want a default page to be displayed when a request comes to the web server that is not configured in the VHosts (for Example de IP-Address). For example Welcome on bla bla bla.

I would like to mention that after every change I reloaded the webserver and all file permissions are correct.

My configs:

sites-enabled:

000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
#ServerName www.example.com

ServerAdmin admin@vaorra.net
DocumentRoot /websites/www/

<Directory /websites/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            Require all granted
</Directory>

# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

openair-seuzach.ch.conf:

```
<VirtualHost openair-seuzach.ch:80>

    ServerName openair-seuzach.ch

    ServerAdmin admin@vaorra.net

    DocumentRoot /websites/openair-seuzach.ch/
    <Directory /websites/openair-seuzach.ch/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

 </VirtualHost>
```

vaorra.net.conf:

```
<VirtualHost vaorra.net:80>

    ServerName vaorra.net

    ServerAdmin admin@vaorra.net

    DocumentRoot /websites/vaorra.net/
    <Directory /websites/vaorra.net/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

My server is running when you want to test it by your self:
http://vaorra.net -> Should be come "Coming Soon"
http://openair-seuzach.ch -> Should be come "Wartung!"

and when you go on http://alligatorgfx.com/ there also comes "Wartung!" but with this domain I want the 000-Default VHost Site displayed and not the site from the openair-seuzach VHost.

My apache2.conf file:

```
DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}

PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

Timeout 300

KeepAlive On

MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

KeepAliveTimeout 5

User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

LogLevel warn

IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

Include ports.conf

AccessFileName .htaccess
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-                                                Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

Thanks!

Comment: `apachectl -S` output please?

Comment: [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @covener https://hastebin.com/icarewudak.js

Comment: @jww it's [already been posted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/484470/100397) to [unix.SE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`apachectl -S` output in the comments says what you intended to be your non-default virtual hosts are not using the same address specification as the one you intended to be the default.

In other words, the first listed `<VirtualHost *:80>` is only the default for all vhosts with exactly `<VirtualHost *:80>` .  Since you have exact matches, like `<VirtualHost 192.168.1.0:80>` Apache will not even consider the wildcard *:80 much less use it as the default/catch-all.

Comment: So I have to use everywhere `<VirtualHost *:80>`?